# Weird behavior Angular 1.3 when copy item in NG-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I came up a very weird behaviour in Angular 1.3:

It happens when I change

```
 {{item}}
```

into:

```
 {{::item}}
```

and click the "Copy" button; what it suppose to do is copy the item at the given index and place it below the source item. What it does instead is copy the last item from the list and add it at the bottom of the list!

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">{{::item}}</li>
        </ul>
        <input ng-model="newItem" type="text"></input>
        <button ng-click="add(newItem)">Add</button>
        <button ng-click="copy(newItem)">Copy</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
    $scope.add = function(item) {
       $scope.items.push(item);
    };
    $scope.copy = function(item) {
       var newItem = angular.copy($scope.items[parseInt(item)]);
       $scope.items.splice(parseInt(item) + 1, 0, newItem);
    };    
});
```

Anybody knows what is going on under the hood?

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v87kgwud/14/

Comment: How will it know the index?

Comment: If you open the JSFiddle; as you can see the item should be typed in the textbox. I.E. when you type 0 and click Copy, it should copy "A" and place it under the source item.

Comment: Basically, I think that AngularJS doesn't insert a new item in the DOM, it only push it at the end, and update the corresponding scopes. But since the textual content can't change (because of one-time binding), you can't see the difference before and after a copy. I'm still searching a solution for you and some proofs of what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

I think Sidharth Panwar's answer is correct for the most part except one.

**Explanation:** 
The initial state of the list is `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` and the first 4 elements are *one time bounded* (i.e a change in their value will not be reflected on UI), but under any event, if the input was in the range 0-3, a new element is added to the list and the last character `'D'` in the list is pushed to fifth place. Since the item at the 5th place in the list is not one time bounded, a new D is rendered on the list.

**Trace**:

1. Initial State: **`['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`**
2. Duplicate 'A' by giving 0 as input to text box
3. New State: **`['A','A','B', 'C'`**`,'D']`

Since the first 4 elements are one time bounded the list will not change the value that was bound in the first digest cycle, however since a new element is found at the fifth place it has to do a one time binding for that new element.

Adding any element before or at the place of D in the list will shift the last element by one place, since this new element is not bound, a one time bound is created. But in this case, it seems that the new element will always be `'D'` because it is at the tail of the list.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think your explanation makes more sense, but still no answer on my question actually; in my code I deep copy $scope.items[parseInt(item)] which points to the correct item at that time. Besides when I fill in "X" and press the "Ädd" button, the correct value is added at the end. It is still a mystery why it doesn't work!

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I found in the angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):
**An expression that starts with :: is considered a one-time expression. One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable.**

This effectively means that when the page is being rendered and ng-repeat runs the iteration happens correctly and values are printed in correct order. Once ng-repeat ends the value assigned to {{::item}} is 'D'. If there is a change in the collection length the ng-repeat will add a new item but that item is D every time because {{::item}} resolves to D. This happens regardless of the copy function working properly and adding the correct element to the collection. So, your collection is no longer the source of truth. This is what one-time binding means - that you're no longer connected to the source. Here's the full verbatim:
Why this feature
The main purpose of one-time binding expression is to provide a way to create a binding that gets deregistered and frees up resources once the binding is stabilized. Reducing the number of expressions being watched makes the digest loop faster and allows more information to be displayed at the same time.

> **Why this feature**
>
> The main purpose of one-time binding expression is to provide a way to
>   create a binding that gets deregistered and frees up resources once
>   the binding is stabilized. Reducing the number of expressions being
>   watched makes the digest loop faster and allows more information to be
>   displayed at the same time.
>
> **Value stabilization algorithm**
>
> One-time binding expressions will retain the value of the expression
>   at the end of the digest cycle as long as that value is not undefined.
>   If the value of the expression is set within the digest loop and
>   later, within the same digest loop, it is set to undefined, then the
>   expression is not fulfilled and will remain watched.
>
> 1. Given an expression that starts with ::, when a digest loop is entered and expression is dirty-checked, store the value as V
> 2. If V is not undefined, mark the result of the expression as stable and schedule a task to deregister the watch for this expression when
>      we exit the digest loop
> 3. Process the digest loop as normal
> 4. When digest loop is done and all the values have settled, process the queue of watch deregistration tasks. For each watch to be
>      deregistered, check if it still evaluates to a value that is not
>      undefined. If that's the case, deregister the watch. Otherwise, keep
>      dirty-checking the watch in the future digest loops by following the
>      same algorithm starting from step 1

Comment: This solution is not OK since the copy button is getting iterated. I don't want that.

Comment: Before downvoting please check your own code. I was just playing with your fiddle. Anyways, please see my updated answer.

Comment: I don't know if this answer solves my issue..your answer doesn't really clarifies why adding an item does work. Also $scope.items[parseInt(item)] does point to the correct item in the collection either

Comment: $scope.items[parseInt(item)] points to the correct item but by the time the collection changes your {{::item}} has been resolved to 'D' so the length item forces the addition of a new item but the value which gets added is 'D'. The whole point of one-way binding is that it'll not keep on checking the source again and again.